# making request in server on behalf of client instead of server

Tags: php, symfony, http

I have the following scenario. A person makes a request to my server, a controller handles this request. Inside this controller code I have a logic that makes another GET request to some endpoint. Is it possible to have/make the request to this GET endpoint on behalf of this person's IP address (use it as a proxy) instead of the server's IP address ??

Comment: I don't think you will find a ethical way to do this, since what you're asking is essentially a security breach, making requests on someone's behalf, or masquerading

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your server is making this request, server IP will be used, this is legit. As for http, you can use x-forwarded-for header to point recipient that your server is used like proxy for client.

Another solution is to force client to make this request via some sort of callbacks.